# leaflet.extras: measure distance in metres

Tags: r, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I would like to create a map where I can interactively measure the distance between 2 points. Luckily, `leaflet.extras` has exactly what I need, however, I'm struggling to get it to produce the outputs in **metres** (or kilometres) as opposed to feet.

Consider the  below piece of code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addDrawToolbar(
    editOptions=editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions=selectedPathOptions())
  )
```

It creates the following map:
[image]

However, [this](http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet-draw) example (chunk 3) effectively the same code to create the same measuring tool (polyline), except it works in KM, whereas my example works in feet.

If you have any tips that can help me switch to metres as opposed to feet, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `drawPolylineOptions` function does not allow to set the option `feet=FALSE`.
Hence, I suggest to modify `drawPolylineOptions` as follows:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

mydrawPolylineOptions <- function (allowIntersection = TRUE, 
    drawError = list(color = "#b00b00", timeout = 2500), 
    guidelineDistance = 20, metric = TRUE, feet = FALSE, zIndexOffset = 2000, 
    shapeOptions = drawShapeOptions(fill = FALSE), repeatMode = FALSE) {
    leaflet::filterNULL(list(allowIntersection = allowIntersection, 
        drawError = drawError, guidelineDistance = guidelineDistance, 
        metric = metric, feet = feet, zIndexOffset = zIndexOffset,
        shapeOptions = shapeOptions,  repeatMode = repeatMode)) }

leaflet() %>% setView(10.975342,45.421588,9) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.Mapnik) %>%
  addDrawToolbar(
    polylineOptions = mydrawPolylineOptions(metric=TRUE, feet=FALSE),
    editOptions=editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions=selectedPathOptions())
  )
```

[image]

Otherwise, using `addMeasures` you can add to your map a useful tool to measure distances (see the icon at the top right corner of the map).
It is possibile to specify units used to display length results by the `primaryLengthUnit` option.

```
leaflet() %>% setView(10.975342,45.421588,9) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addDrawToolbar(
    editOptions=editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions=selectedPathOptions())
  ) %>% 
  addMeasure(primaryLengthUnit="kilometers", secondaryLengthUnit="kilometers")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Marco, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: And as a follow-up, would you know if there is an easy way to get the "draw a circle" feature of the `addDrawToolbar()` function to also display the radius in km? Many thanks :)

Comment: @IVR This is an interesting question. Please, post a new question for the SO community!

Comment: @MarcoSandriI would be more than happy to take a PR on the draw feature to include the metric/feet argument.

Comment: @BhaskarKarambelkar Sorry, I do not understand. Please, explain me in more detail your problem.